# What is the equivalent of perl's Win32::OLE::Variant in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, win32ole

I have the following code snippet in perl for automating an application script using `Win32::OLE`

```
    use Win32::OLE;
    use Win32::OLE::Variant;
    my $app = new Win32::OLE 'Some.Application';
    my $InfoPacket = "78 00 C4 10 95 B4
                      00 02 31 7F 80 FF";
    my @Bytes = split(/[ \n][ \n]*/, $InfoPacket);
    my @HexBytes;
    foreach(@Bytes)
    {
        push @HexBytes, eval "0x$_";
    }
    my $Packet = pack("C12", @HexBytes);
    my $VarPacket = Variant(VT_UI1, $Packet);
    my $InfoObj = app -> ProcessPacket($VarPacket);
    print $InfoObj -> Text();
```

I have converted the entire code in Python 3, except for the [exact] equivalent of `pack()` and `Variant()` functions.

```
    from win32com.client import Dispatch
    from struct import pack
    app = Dispatch("Some.Application")
    InfoPacket = "78 00 C4 10 95 B4 \
                  00 02 31 7F 80 FF"
    Bytes = InfoPacket.split()
    HexBytes = [int(b, 16) for b in Bytes]
    Packet = pack('B'*12, *HexBytes)       # This however, is not giving the exact same output as perl's...
    VarPacket = ...                         # Need to know the python equivalent of above Variant() function...
    InfoObj = app.ProcessPacket(VarPacket)
    print (InfoObj.Text())
```

Please suggest the python equivalent of the `pack()` and `Variant()` functions used in perl script in the given context so that the final variable `VarPacket` can be used by Python's `Dispatch` object to properly generate the `InfoObj` object.

Thanks !!!

Comment: First compare Perl's [Win32::OLE::Variant](https://metacpan.org/source/JDB/Win32-OLE-0.1713/lib/Win32/OLE/Variant.pm) with Python's [win32com.client.VARIANT](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/e0a7d99d7fe770e6eda58c1fa0988e7cc48f9b97/com/win32com/client/__init__.py#L542). Check [this win32com example](https://web.archive.org/web/20200709211351/http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/html/com/win32com/HTML/variant.html) , and have a look [at the tests for it](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/5f1028fdfb7c9c52f8d30c2c766100d1c7113838/com/win32com/test/testPyComTest.py#L540) too.

Comment: And Perl's pack function [has docs here](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the Python equivalent of the Perl `Variant`, but for the first question about packing the unsigned char array, the following works for me:

```
from struct import pack

def gen_list():
    info_packet = "78 00 C4 10 95 B4 00 02 31 7F 80 FF"
    count = 0
    for hex_str in info_packet.split():
        yield int(hex_str, 16)
        count += 1
    for j in range(count, 120):
        yield int(0)


packet = pack("120B", *list(gen_list()))
```

**Edit**

From the test file [testPyComTest.py](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/5f1028fdfb7c9c52f8d30c2c766100d1c7113838/com/win32com/test/testPyComTest.py#L540) it looks like you can generate the variant like this:

```
import win32com.client
import pythoncom

variant = win32com.client.VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_ARRAY | pythoncom.VT_UI1, packet)
```

Comment: Haegland,
Sorry for the confusion. Wrote 120 instead of 12. Have edited the same.

I implemented your code but couldn't get the desired output.
The InfoObj is coming out to be a `<COMObject ProcessPacket>` itself and not "AutoPacket" object which is the return type of ProcessPacket() function. And when I am trying `print(InfoObj.Text())`, it is giving error, `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`.